# How to stop false patent infringement claims

Tags: patent-infringement, patent-services

I've found a product that was implemented poorly and have redesigned it. Completely. It appears the same, as in it looks almost identical from a distance, but it isn't. It's a glove.

After reviewing intensively the existing patent and reworking everything from material to sewing pattern I'm being accused of violating someones patent and because it looks the same, people are buying into it.

**False** online claims and emails to my clients of the last 9 yrs, have persisted for a couple of years now, yet not once has there been any *follow up* action taken on anyone actively selling our product.

One client, contacted 2 yrs ago, stopped selling this product after she contacted him. (He's been our client 9yrs and still sells our other products.) He bought hers and within a month was back to selling our product and hasn't heard from her since. He sells hundreds.

Nothing has been proven in a court of law yet this person is causing havoc. How can I stop this without filing my own patent?

I have a 9 min full patent overview video and a 3 min "cut to the chase" patent explain-er video.

Thanks for taking the time...It is much appreciated.
Tom

EDIT: What if I wanted an attorney to give his opinion on whether or not our product infringed on this one patent. Would this be feasible? Is it something that is practiced? I don't need a full patent search, I just need some confirmation, short of a court decision, that backs up our claims.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like it's asking for pretty specific legal advice. I'd definitely advise speaking with an attorney.